# .get() how to change variable to value

Tags: python, list, variables

I want that if I put a variable it will change to its value, but if it is an integer it will not change.

```
Element={"C":4,"O":6}

a=input("Compound Formula = ")
b=a.split()
n=len(b)
print(b)
print(n)

Formula=[Element.get(val,"") for val in a]

print(Formula)
```

If I use this code, when I enter `C1O2` it gives me the output `[4,0,6,0]`

The way I want it, if I enter `C1O2` it must give `[4,1,6,2]`
so that later I can multiply 4 by 1 and 6 by 2
and I can calculate the amount of valence electron by adding them.

Comment: What language are we talking about here? It sounds like you're using split() where perhaps what you need is some kind of parser for reading chemical formulas...

Comment: I use split so that when I input a compound it will break it into a list, which will tell me what element are there and how much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a helper function to do that during parsing

```
Element={"C":4,"O":6}

def parse_only_elment(val, elelments):
    if (val in elements):
        return Element.get(val,"")
    else:
        return val
a=input("Compound Formula = ")
b=a.split()
n=len(b)
print(b)
print(n)

Formula=[parse_only_elment(val, Element) for val in a]

print(Formula)
```

Comment: can you actually change str in a dictionary into int?

Comment: just return int(element.get(val, ")

Comment: what is the function of  `def parse_only_elment(val, elelments)` when `def parse_only_elment(val)` will give the same output?

Comment: it depend on your use case one can be easier reusable than the other

Comment: i still dont get it example maybe i am still new so this is important for adding my knowledge